# Disable Top Nav Bar on Mobile

Tags: menus, css, navigation, mobile, screen-layout

I've created a site (www.smartgrowtheconomics.com) using the 2017 theme plus some extra CSS that looks fine on a desktop and tablet, but persistently shows a blue dropdown menu and search bar on a smartphone. I've tried some CSS-ery, including

.navigation-top {
        display: none;
    }

and

.main-navigation {
    visibility:hidden;
}

but not managed to remove the bar, menu, and search bar. I don't know JS, but I've pasted snippets with instructions before. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your issue? If so, please accept it so we can close this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the whole blue section at the top (menu and a search input field), you should add this to your CSS:

```
.menu-search { display: none; }
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this code helped to answer your question, please accept it. Thanks.